# traversing a directory

Tags: c++, boost

Is there any way to traverse the content of a directory? I would like to store the names of each folder in a given directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

According to the tags you're interested in C++/Boost. Then, kindly borrowing from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497243/what-are-all-the-ways-to-traverse-directory-trees/1978283#1978283):

```
#include <utility>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(top), eod;
foreach (fs::path const & p, std::make_pair(it, eod)) {
    if (is_directory(p)) {
        ...
    } else if (is_regular_file(p)) {
        ...
    } else if (is_symlink(p)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Another version, taken from [Rosetta code:](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#C.2B.2B)

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
  path current_dir("."); //
  boost::regex pattern("a.*"); // list all files starting with a
  for (recursive_directory_iterator iter(current_dir), end;
       iter != end;
       ++iter)
  {
    std::string name = iter->path().leaf();
    if (regex_match(name, pattern))
      std::cout << iter->path() << "\n";
  }
}
```