# Bash - Printing Directory Files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

What's the best way to print all the files listed in a directory and the numer of files using a for loop? Is there a better of doing this?

```
#!/bin/bash

target="/home/personal/scripts/07_22_13/ford/$1"

for file in "$target"/*
do
  printf "%s\n" "$file" | cut -d"/" -f8
done
```

Comment: Note that the script does not know the `$HOME` var, so you have to use `/home...`.

Comment: Is there a way to perhaps not have to include the entire path? That would definitely make it easier on the user. @fedorqui

Comment: Mmm maybe you can define an initial path structure like `path=/home/this_user` and then check `$path/$directory`.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? how is your script related to the question in the subject?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1978230/489590 walks a tree, so your question is a special case that should be answered by it.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. It's like assigning a halfway path to a variable that way the user only has to worry about the name of the directory.

Comment: @umläute I couldn't figure out why the script wasn't finding the given directory until I realized what fedorqui had stated about having to declare the full path. Other than that I wanted to know the best way of looping through a directory and printing all of the files contained inside.

Comment: I've re-edited the post. @umläute

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

target="/home/personal/scripts/07_22_13/ford/$1"
let count=0
for f in "$target"/*
do
    echo $(basename $f)
    let count=count+1
done
echo ""
echo "Count: $count"
```

## Solution 2

If you don't want to deal with parsing the path to get just the file names, another solution is to `cd` into the directory in question, do your business, and `cd` back to where you were:

```
#!/bin/bash

target="/home/personal/scripts/07_22_13/ford/$1"
pushd "$target" > /dev/null
let count=0
for f in *
do
    echo $f
    let count=count+1
done
popd
echo ""
echo "Count: $count"
```

The `pushd` and `popd` commands will switch to a directory, then return.

Comment: What would you use to format the output of the files to just see the file names? I ended up using cut, but what would you suggest?

Comment: I came up with this: awk -F '/' '{ print $8 | "sort" }' I'll look at basename in just a second.

Comment: I like basename, I figured something else out as well. You could also do something like: echo ${f##*/} | sort

Answer (score 0):

```
target="/home/personal/scripts/07_22_13/ford/$1"
for f in "$target"/*; do
    basename "$f"
done | awk 'END { printf("File count: %d", NR); } NF=NF'
```

`basename "$f"` will automatically output each filename on its own line, and the awk code will print the total number of records processed, which is this case is the number of files listed. Additionally, awk will automatically print the filenames because of the `NF=NF` pattern at the end. I'd say learning awk can be advantageous, as shown here. :-)